# To what part of the object should the origin correspond in object space?

Tags: opengl

When defining an object's vertices, I'm unsure if the origin (of the object space) should correspond to the middle of the object or some other part of the object like the top/bottom left corner. It seems to me that the middle would make rotations easier, while a top/bottom left corner origin would make positioning easier. I'm wondering what the convention is in the OpenGL world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your application, but given that the vertices are going to be translated by things like the Model Matrix or by other transformations you use, a good convention is to define the box that completely encloses the object as <-1,-1,-1> to <1,1,1> and to use vertices relative to that shape.

In other words, the Vertices should describe the object in abstract space. Don't use them to think about positioning relative to other objects or to the world around them; that's what the Model Matrix is for.

Comment: But won't the positioning code have to change if we change the box in object space? For example what if I take <0, 0, 0> to <1, 1, 1> as my box instead of yours. Will this have an effect on the object's position in world space?

Comment: @DaanDeMeyer To an extent, yes. But again, the Model Matrix should be performing all the translations necessary to properly position the object. Whether that be assuming the object is centered around `<0,0,0>` or translating by `<-0.5,-0.5,-0.5>` in your case, or whatever convention most accurately models the object, it should be done on the Model Matrix, not in the Vertices.